# smart-table with pagination - Set the last page by default

Tags: angularjs, smart-table

I'm using the very good table library [Smart-table](http://lorenzofox3.github.io/smart-table-website/) to display my data.

I am using a custom pagination template. I would however like to be able to set the page to the last one so I could see the last item added.

This is the pagination.html :

```
<nav ng-if="pages.length >= 2">
<ul class="pagination">
    <li>
        <a ng-click="selectPage(1)">First</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a ng-click="selectPage(currentPage - 1)">&lt;</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a><page-select></page-select> of {{numPages}}</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a ng-click="selectPage(currentPage + 1)">&gt;</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a ng-click="selectPage(numPages)">Last</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And this is the directive

```
angular.module('myApp')
.directive('pageSelect', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<input type="text" class="select-page" ng-model="inputPage" ng-change="selectPage(inputPage)">',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.$watch('currentPage', function(c) {
        scope.inputPage = c;
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call the function `selectPage(numPages)` from your controller.